# Add sidecar with DLLs to Tauri

Tags: rust, tauri

I've got a Tauri project which includes a few sidecars, one of the sidecars requires DLLs. I am able to bundle the sidecar binary exe file but not the DLLs. I've tried adding the DLLs as resources but Tauri puts the sidecar executables in the root installation directory and the resources are mapped to where they were located in the src directory. I could move the DLLs to the src directory however I feel that would be extremely messy.

I have also considered statically linking the program I am attempting to add as a sidecar but that might not always be an option.